# querying SQLite database for dates

Tags: c++, winapi, sqlite

I am new to databases and experimenting with SQLite latest version 3.25.2

I setup a simple database with file information, storing the date as an ISO STRING (text). A query for all items shows:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM dir", callback, 0, 0);
```

results in (printout through the callback)

```
system.NAME = New File.txt
modified = '2018-11-03 11:35:42'
system.NAME = ReadMe.txt
modified = '2018-11-01 10:43:21'
...
```

but when I try to query for a particular date (files more recent than said date), the query comes out empty!?

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM dir WHERE modified > '2018-11-02 00:00:00'", callback, 0, 0);
```

whereas as you can see from the files in the database above, at least one (New file.txt) should match the query. I also tried storing dates as integers and as real, without any luck

it must be something silly but I cannot see it :(

Comment: Why are you storing timestamps as strings anyway? A 64-bit integer will be much easier to work with. Have a look at the [SQLite Date & Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: I tried that too. Integer date (stored as UNIX time) but compare to string date won't work either(WHERE modified > '2018-11-...')

Comment: So then, why are you comparing timestamps using string comparisons? Why don't you compare timestamps against timestamps, i.e. trivial integer arithmetic? Your problem appears to be more complex because you are making it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Have you checked what's in your database using the sqlite3 command line tool?  I tried your query with your example data and it works fine.

Comment: Also, show your schema.

Comment: Also, why in the world are you using sqlite3_exec to try to retrieve data? Use [prepared statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html); the interface is so much easier to work with.

Comment: And more required reading: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html (especially the section on comparisons if you don't know why comparing an integer and a string didn't work)

Comment: obviously comparing integers with strings should not work, but given that SQLite doesn't have a date data type, there should be a way to compare an integer (stored) date with a string representation equivalent... I suppose the only solution is to create a custom function? (because all documented date functions return strings)

Comment: reading the docs more carefully I see that strftime can return a number as UNIX time. But it doesn't work. Perhaps the return is mistaken for a string. But I found another solution: store dates as REAL (julian) then use this clause: WHERE modified > julianday('2018-11-02 00:00:00')

Answer (score 0):

Using :-

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dir (system_name TEXT, modified TEXT);",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"INSERT INTO dir VALUES('New File.txt','2018-11-03 11:35:42'),('Readme.txt','2018-11-01 10:43:21');",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM dir;",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM dir WHERE modified > '2018-11-02 00:00:00';",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
```

Results in :-

```
system_name = New File.txt
modified = 2018-11-03 11:35:42

system_name = Readme.txt
modified = 2018-11-01 10:43:21

system_name = New File.txt
modified = 2018-11-03 11:35:42
```

However considering your output has **single quotes** wrapped around the dates in the output, then :-

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dir (system_name TEXT, modified TEXT);",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"DELETE FROM dir;",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"INSERT INTO dir VALUES('New File.txt','''2018-11-03 11:35:42'''),('Readme.txt','''2018-11-01 10:43:21''');",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED single quotes
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM dir;",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM dir WHERE modified > '2018-11-02 00:00:00';",callback,0,&zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
```

Does produce your result. Basically because the single quote is taken into consideration as it's stored (at least it appears so from the uotput you have shown) as part of the value.

So the fix to the query would be to use :-

```
sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM dir WHERE modified > '''2018-11-02 00:00:00''';",callback,0,0);
```

However, it would probably be best to not enclose the value in single quotes.

Comment: thanks guys, the quotes were the problem, and now it works nicely. It was some copy/paste problem from old code. And regarding prepared statements, thanks, this is just testing code and I will do better with production code :)